# Compactify the input

Tags: code-golf, string, compression

Given a word, your task is to compact it by saving its first character and removing any other vowel (aeiou).

## Input

Your input can be the word in STDIN, a function argument or any other input format that doesn't break the [standard loopholes](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1061/loopholes-that-are-forbidden-by-default).  You can assume the input only consists of lower characters.

## Output

Your output must be the word, compacted.

## Examples

```
i -> i
ate -> at
potato -> ptt
ksboejqfgcrauxpwivtzndlhmy -> ksbjqfgcrxpwvtzndlhmy
```

## Score

This is a code-golf, so shortest answer in bytes wins, good luck!

Answer (score 7):

## [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E), 6 bytes

```
ćsžMм«
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##yy9OTMpM/f//SHvx0X2@F/YcWv3/f0F@SWJJPgA)

## Explanation

```
       Input (e.g.). potato
ć      Head extract. otato, p
 s     Swap        . p, otato
  žM   Vowels      . p, otato, aeiou
    м  Remove      . p, tt
     « Concatenate . ptt

Implicit output    .
```

Answer (score 5):

## [Retina](https://github.com/m-ender/retina/wiki/The-Language), <s>15</s> <s>13</s> 8 bytes

```
0T1,`v`_
```

`T`ransliterates lowercase `v`owels into nothing (`_`) in the `0`th in 0-indexing match of the implicit regex that matches the entire string, after index 1 (`1,`).

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K0otycxLNPz/3yDEUCehLCH@///EkozUzOJcAA)

Answer (score 5):

## [C (gcc)](https://gcc.gnu.org/), <s>57 56</s> 52 bytes

Time to roll out some magic numbers!

*Thanks @Arnauld for even better magic numbers!*

```c
f(char*a,char*b){for(*b++=*a;*b=*++a;)b+=4373%*a&1;}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##HcpLDoIwEADQqxgSTDutCQQTF5OexLiYqRZQKZ@CP8LZq7J6m2d3pbUxOmErGoD0CsvZtYMAVsoAIbABpQglK7MvDkUKtM1xif@7oWOeZSfNK9hQ7YWcgyXvRJKGRJNEJ0izxG4ag/i5RCK254srq/p6uze@7fohjNPj@Xp/vg)

Comment: so those magic numbers check if something is a vowel?

Comment: [repost] Yes. I found that by enumerating those constants.

Comment: [52 bytes](https://tio.run/##HcpLDoIwEADQqxgSTDutCQQTF5OexLiYqRZQKZ@CP8LZq7J6m2d3pbUxOmErGoD0CsvZtYMAVsoAIbABpQglK7MvDkUKtM1xif@7oWOeZSfNK9hQ7YWcgyXvRJKGRJNEJ0izxG4ag/i5xFvg9nLtXWkHml7ds36MH3@@V837Cw)

Comment: Thanks! Very nice. @Arnauld

Answer (score 4):

## [J](http://jsoftware.com/), 15 bytes

```
{.,'aeiou'-.~}.
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##RY3BTsMwEETv/YpRLkulxOIciQtInFAP/IGbbugWxzb1mjZU5deDo1BYaaXRzNudw1QZ6vHQglDjHm3ZxuDp9eV5upiaLEvI1Jjvq5nWK@72AXc1Ca3RtOgxS8yzeTQQH7OCzx1HleBbbEfsuLfZKWZOEqyH1TDUSAEnxpDTfBCddOpGVOydJK0gapYuskpLU1FMv2bUPzcGLQ9vwXvaHj76t@54jqdP/fI7tx/GG1rCwEtscwHkn1hNPw)

Straightforward:

- `{.` head...
- `,` catted with...
- `'aeiou'-.~` vowels, set minused from...
- `}.` tail

Answer (score 4):

## [sed](https://www.gnu.org/software/sed/), 14 bytes

```
s/\B[aeiou]//g
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K05N0U3PK/3/v1g/xik6MTUzvzRWXz/9//9MrsSSVK6C/JLEknyu7OKk/NSswrT05KLE0oqC8syykqq8lJyM3EoA)

---

## [Bash](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/) + Core utilities, 19 bytes

```bash
sed s/\\B[aeiou]//g
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S0oszvj/vzg1RaFYPybGKToxNTO/NFZfP/3//0yuxJJUroL8ksSSfK7s4qT81KzCtPTkosTSioLyzLKSqryUnIzcSgA)

Comment: `sed` solution is nice.

Answer (score 4):

## [Python 2](https://docs.python.org/2/), 43 bytes

Another 43-byte solution in Python.

```python
lambda s:s[0]+s[1:].translate(None,'aeiou')
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##DctBDsIgEADAO6/gVojGWI8kfsEPtI3ZWpBVCgiLWD@Pzn3iRjb4UzPnsTlY5wV4Vnk4Trs89Go6UAKfHZAWl@D1vgONoXSyVYtO814xHhN64kYkqFf0sZCQsiH7FxYDAQX2zHPQj5e53xKUT6z4pq9fnF23Hw)

Answer (score 4):

## [Ruby](https://www.ruby-lang.org/en/), 31 bytes

```
->x{x[0]+x[1..].tr('aeiou','')}
```

Needs to be run on Ruby 2.6 or above, since it uses an endless range.

(TIO is on 2.5.5, so it doesn't work there.)

Answer (score 4):

## Excel, 87 bytes

```
=LET(q,SEQUENCE(LEN(A1)),x,MID(A1,q,1),CONCAT(IF(ISERROR(FIND(x,"aeiou"))+(q=1),x,"")))
```

Hopefully this link works.
[Try it here](https://1drv.ms/x/s!AkqhtBc2XEHJm3v9rEGTcan1-PiT?e=iUq5sb)

Comment: Is there an online Excel simulator to run this?  My own (outdated) Excel version doesn't seem to have functions like ```LET``` or ```SEQUENCE```....

Comment: Added link.  Hopefully, it works.

Answer (score 3):

## [Python 3](https://docs.python.org/3/), <s>44</s> 43 bytes

```python
lambda a,*s:[a]+[c[c in"aeiou":]for c in s]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##PYoxcoMwEEV7nWJHjcHBNOmYwRchFGtA8Togydq1HcJwdiKRmXT/v/f8LFdn3zdTf2wjTpceAYsjVw22b03XdEBW40DuoavWuAAJALcbTd4FAZ5ZJTySHXYzc8nSk60UABcBapjQZywh4kC@2MuS/UiS6dNZ53kM0XIMD4fy5shmJjvyjn0gK5nRC69wOsMSsxWaZa9rCGur842SIYUypIGivBMUl44XUV98ccPtbj67gI9v/6Kn/Nh@vE5zKqL9c9H8i18)

**Input**: Characters of the word. E.g `f("a", "t", "e")`
**Output**: A list of characters.

Comment: [Alternative 43 bytes using regex](https://tio.run/##PYoxcoMwEEV7nWKHBpjBNOk8g4tcw3axBCneBCR5d0lCGM5OJCeT7r//Xlz0FvzT7rrLPuLUDwh4ZNvK3Ffl5fmMdqZwLZuybLA2NMXACmz3vyWLGBcYRvIWyGduRQfyRwMgDUMHE8ZKlNPNFJtH2UocSavicCrqOoXoJYWukgyRyWvlilU2OJxgTXKD8/poOuDtWtQ7ZUMG1eaBamJQ1JAhqpp36YN9u7vXF8b5K37Sh377YbxNSy6S/XXJ/Isf)

Comment: @CommandMaster nice! Since the approach is quite different from mine, why don't you post this as a separate answer?

Answer (score 3):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), 6 [bytes](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly/wiki/Code-page)

```
Ḣ;ḟØẹ$
```

**[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##ASAA3/9qZWxsef//4biiO@G4n8OY4bq5JP///2FiY2RlZmdoaQ)**

#### How?

```
Ḣ;ḟØẹ$ - Link: list of characters, W
Ḣ      - head & yield
     $ - last two links as a monad - i.e. f(rest of W)
  ḟ    -   filter discard:
   Øẹ  -     lower-case vowels
 ;     - (head of W) concatenate (f(rest of W))
```

Comment: I just arrived at the exact same solution before noticing this one. I think the one thing worth mentioning in the explanation is that `Ḣ` mutates the input

Comment: Yep - "head & yield" and "rest of W".

Answer (score 3):

## [naz](https://github.com/sporeball/naz), 102 bytes

```
2x1v2a6m8m1a2x2v4a2x3v4a2x4v6a2x5v6a2x6v1x1f1r3x1v2e3x2v1e3x3v1e3x4v1e3x5v1e3x6v1e1o1f0x1x2f0a0x1r1o1f
```

Works for any null-terminated input string.

[Try it online!](https://sporeball.dev/naz/?code=2x1v2a6m8m1a2x2v4a2x3v4a2x4v6a2x5v6a2x6v1x1f1r3x1v2e3x2v1e3x3v1e3x4v1e3x5v1e3x6v1e1o1f0x1x2f0a0x1r1o1f&input=compactify&n=true)

**Explanation** (with `0x` instructions removed)

```
2x1v                                           # Set variable 1 equal to 0
2a6m8m1a2x2v                                   # Set variable 2 equal to 97 ("a")
4a2x3v                                         # Set variable 3 equal to 101 ("e")
4a2x4v                                         # Set variable 4 equal to 105 ("i")
6a2x5v                                         # Set variable 5 equal to 111 ("o")
6a2x6v                                         # Set variable 6 equal to 117 ("u")
1x1f                                           # Function 1
    1r                                         # Read a byte of input
      3x1v2e                                   # Goto function 2 if it equals variable 1
            3x2v1e3x3v1e3x4v1e3x5v1e3x6v1e     # Jump back to the start of the function
                                               # if it equals variable 2, 3, 4, 5, or 6
                                          1o1f # Otherwise, output it, then call the
                                               # function again
1x2f                                           # Function 2
    0a                                         # Add 0 to the register
1r1o                                           # Output the first byte of input
1f                                             # Call function 1
```

Answer (score 2):

## [Erlang (escript)](http://erlang.org/doc/man/escript.html), 26 bytes

```erlang
f([H|T])->[H]++T--"aeiou".
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##Sy3KScxL100tTi7KLCj5z/U/TSPaoyYkVlPXLtojVls7RFdXKTE1M79USe9/bmJmnka8poKuHZcCEGTmW5UXZZakaqRpKBXklySW5Ctpaur9BwA)

### Explanation

```erlang
f([H|T])->       % Match the head & tail of the input string.
[H]              % Wrap the head in a list,
   ++T           % Append the tail
      --"aeiou". % with all vowels removed.
```

Answer (score 2):

## [APL (Dyalog)](https://www.dyalog.com/), 14 bytes

```apl
⊃,'aieou'~⍨1∘↓
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##SyzI0U2pTMzJT///P@1R24RHXc066omZqfml6nWPelcYPuqY8ahtMlBOQT2xJFWdC0gX5JckluSDmdnFSfmpWYVp6clFiaUVBeWZZSVVeSk5GbmV6gA)

Answer (score 2):

## [Haskell](https://www.haskell.org/), 34 bytes

```hs
f(a:s)=a:[x|x<-s,notElem x"aeiou"]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0gszk7Nyfn/P00j0apY0zbRKrqipsJGt1gnL7/ENSc1V6FCKTE1M79UKfZ/bmJmnoKtQkFpSXBJkU@egopCmoJSYklGamZxrtJ/AA)

Comment: You can do `all(/=x)` for `notElem x`.

Answer (score 2):

## [Perl 5](https://www.perl.org/) `-p`, 18 bytes

```perl
s/(?<!^)[aeiou]//g
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K0gtyjH9/79YX8PeRjFOMzoxNTO/NFZfP/3//0yuxJJUroL8ksSS/H/5BSWZ@XnF/3ULcgA)

Comment: Hey, came up with prety much the same! You can remove `<` from the lookbehind for one, or if you use the regex as the arg to `-F` you can have a 5 byte solution: [Try it online!](https://tio.run/##Hc05DsIwEEDRPqcYRANCWShSA006TsCimHiACcZj4jEhiLNjIqovveY77EwZp7DRGjXUn72tQRjqtPpXSA8QHOjgDDVKECz2hiz6LHo1rKsYKRk5cSxKOLn5E2P7OF@aToWX6@kpb6vN9T582Qmx9THdltmyyIqYqiqfrSbH@U4hcTgsxnn@Aw "Perl 5 – Try It Online")

Answer (score 2):

**APL ([NARS2000 0.5.13.0](http://www.nars2000.org/)), 20 unicode char (so 20 byte or 40 byte?)**

```
(↑,((~∘'aeiou')1∘↓))
```

Sample output:

```
      (↑,((~∘'aeiou')1∘↓)) 'i'
i
      (↑,((~∘'aeiou')1∘↓)) 'ate'
at
      (↑,((~∘'aeiou')1∘↓)) 'potato'
ptt
      (↑,((~∘'aeiou')1∘↓)) 'ksboejqfgcrauxpwivtzndlhmy' 
ksbjqfgcrxpwvtzndlhmy
      (↑,((~∘'aeiou')1∘↓)) ''
```

Thanks to the tacit feature added lately.

Since APL code chars are unicode chars, I am not sure if one char should be counted as two byte or not.

Comment: I think those are 28 UTF8-bytes.

Answer (score 2):

## [PHP](https://php.net/), 41 bytes

```php
<?=preg_replace("/\\B[aeiou]/","",$argn);
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K8go@P/fxt62oCg1Pb4otSAnMTlVQ0k/JsYpOjE1M780Vl9JR0lJRyWxKD1P0/r//8SSotTK0n/5BSWZ@XnF/3XdAA)

I wanted to find an original solution but it ends up like everyone's regex.. Deception is my middle name

Answer (score 2):

## [PowerShell](https://github.com/TryItOnline/TioSetup/wiki/Powershell), <strike>33</strike> 30 bytes

-3 bytes thanks to @CommandMaster

```powershell
$args-split"(.)[aeiou]"-join''
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K8gvTy0qzkjNyfn/XyWxKL1Yt7ggJ7NESUNPMzoxNTO/NFZJNys/M09d/f///4lJRYnZpSkg6j8A)

Comment: never used powershell, but `$args-split"(.)[aeiou]"-join''` seems to work for -3

Comment: @CommandMaster wow, wouldn't expect that to work, thank you ;)

Comment: ? [Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K8gvTy0qzkjNyfn/XyWxKL1Ytyi1ICcxOVVdw97GVk8zOjE1M780Vv3///@JSUWJ2aUpIOo/AA "PowerShell – Try It Online")

Comment: @mazzy 24 bytes: `$args-replace'\B[aeiou]'`

Answer (score 2):

## [Brachylog](https://github.com/JCumin/Brachylog), 7 bytes

```
h|b;Ḅ∋ᵛ
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##SypKTM6ozMlPN/pfXa6koGunoFRu/6htw6OmpofbFiQ/3NVZ@3DrhP8ZNUnWD3e0POrofrh19v//0UqZSjpKiSWpQLIgvySxJB/IyC5Oyk/NKkxLTy5KLK0oKM8sK6nKS8nJyK0ESqZWlABtSiwG6cgvyUgtgrJz84tSQcxipVgA)

[Generator](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2447/default-for-code-golf-input-output-methods/10753#10753).

```
 |         The output is
h          the first element of the input,
 |         or
     ∋ᵛ    some shared element of
 |b        the input without its first element
   ;Ḅ      and the lowercase consonants.
```

Answer (score 2):

## [Factor](https://factorcode.org/), 31 bytes

```
[ 1 cut "aeiou"without append ]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##DccxDsIwDAXQnVN89QBIrHAAxMKCmBCDSQ0N0NhJHEJBnD10e@9KziS142G3366hic0mTT4YYkXmWDg4zrMsY7OI9QsPMoaKkQke@SJ8j9ebS1TeWv3LPqF/DuOEXzthBVcMHbGX0lVvg8wlVQ49zm0kxbL9AQ)

### Explanation

It's a quotation (anonymous function) that takes one string as input and leaves one string as output. Assuming `"potato"` is on top of the data stack when this quotation is called...

- `1` Push one to the data stack. **Stack:** `"potato" 1`
- `cut` Cut a sequence into two pieces at a given index. **Stack:** `"p" "otato"`
- `"aeiou"` Push a string to the data stack. **Stack:** `"p" "otato" "aeiou"`
- `without` Remove elements from NOS (next on stack) that are in TOS (top of stack). **Stack:** `"p" "tt"`
- `append` Concatenate two strings. **Stack:** `"ptt"`

Answer (score 1):

## [Red](http://www.red-lang.org), 33 bytes

```
func[s][trim/with next s"aeiou"s]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##Tcg7EoAgDADR3lMwuYC9x7BlKFCCxg8gBEUvj51jt28jmtqjkaqxXbXZjTIpyZH29iKehcPCIoFG8hmSqiGSY2EFEDRfa8afgmfN/jfWNHhcDjuNUecSLjr5cWab9xvqCw)

Answer (score 1):

## [Python 3](https://docs.python.org/3/), <sup><s>57</s></sup> 55 bytes

Saved 2 bytes thanks to [ovs](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/64121/ovs)!!!

```python
lambda s:s[0]+''.join(c for c in s[1:]if{c}-{*'aeiou'})
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##PY7BTsMwEETv/oq9rQ1tRCkSUiTzI0kObmpTt6ltvBugRPn2ULeC24zeaPTShQ8xbBen22Uw593eANXUPHWPiNUx@iB7cDFDDz4ANZu6827q5/X0gMb6OOKsFrbEpBFReFi/gReGbQmGRYpsOJaSmMWJdtEeP9x7n834nb78J/@E/XA4X8riSu/sSv6BKLdZyxHb8fn1pccV3ONmi0oUM7OyxU0OFaXBs8TyhepmPRRy06uIs09S/Y3agErVAgg0OGmUgJR9YOlwMnN5mGiGKTekte1mVMvyCw)

Comment: `if c not in'aeiou'` can be 2 bytes shorter with set difference: `if{c}-{*'aeiou'}`

Comment: @ovs That's clever - thanks! :-)

Answer (score 1):

## JavaScript (ES6),  <s>27</s>  26 bytes

*Saved 1 byte thanks to @Neil*

Returns a list of characters.

```javascript
s=>s.match(/^.|[^aeiou]/g)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##jcxLDoIwFIXhuasgTGgHtivAjRhJLqWUIvRWesFH3HttYmIixugZ/9/pYYGgJutp67DRsS1jKHdBjECqY7IS930F2uJ8kIZHhS7goMWAhrUstzkXPVrHioLz7PukzOxmZYH0XzpZoDX2SED42yfs6UMfQ426P7VGTTBf/NkudHPN0I3X98ekU/oMU/aq4gM)

Comment: Why not use `^` instead of `\b`?

Comment: @Neil I saw your comment a while ago and forgot about it. Thanks!

Comment: Is this valid? An array of characters isn't the same thing as a string, in JavaScript.

Answer (score 1):

## [K (oK)](https://github.com/JohnEarnest/ok), 20 bytes

```
{(*x),(1_x)^"aoeiu"}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##FcZBEkAgFADQq5i/USYLW@7ChCLhhyKMs2davadz1CHI8iWZp4wUjac1cBTKwRdkShgoqBLgVkQMWm4xTh8timmTQ7dz582lTvus/TwuN9DwAw)

Answer (score 1):

## [Python 3](https://docs.python.org/3/), 61 bytes

```python
lambda s:s[0]+''.join(filter(lambda x:x not in'aeiou',s[1:]))
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##PY1BDoIwEEX3nqK7tpEYjTsSTlK7KNDKIMzUdlDw8pWFcfPzkpe8HzceCK8lYHMrk5vb3olcZ3O2RylPIwGqABP7pH5yrVeBxAJQOg@0yCqbS221Luwzdy77LBphJMhKOvb7RmLHtMMjt@THZ7h3yS1rfMOLP9hPw7xJezAxAbIKqEBrESgJ2D/EP2rLFw)

Comment: Welcome to the site.  This repeats the first character if it is a consonant.  You should change the `s` to `s[1:]` to prevent this.

Comment: @AdHocGarfHunter Thank you! :)

Answer (score 1):

## [Charcoal](https://github.com/somebody1234/Charcoal), 12 bytes

```
ΦＳ¬∧κ№aeiouι
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S85ILErOT8z5/z@gKDOvRMMtM6cktUjDM6@gtCS4BCiUrqGpo@CXX6LhmJeika2j4JxfClSmlJiamV@qpKOQqQkC1v//JyYVJSYnpoCo/7plOQA) Link is to verbose version of code. Explanation:

```
 Ｓ              Input string
Φ ¬             Exclude characters where
     №aeiouι    Character is a vowel
   ∧κ           And index is not zero
                Implicitly print
```

Answer (score 1):

## [Keg](https://github.com/JonoCode9374/Keg) `-ir`, <s>34</s> 16 bytes

Huge saving thanks to Lyxal.

```
,(:⅍`aeiou`-[,|_
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y05N//9fR8PqUWtvQmJqZn5pgm60Tk38//8FialVmYX5pf91M4sA)

Comment: [16 bytes with `-ir` and some other shenanigans.](https://tio.run/##y05N//9fR8PqUWtvQmJqZn5pgm60Tk38//8FialVmYX5pf91M4sA "Keg – Try It Online")

Answer (score 1):

## [Pyth](https://github.com/isaacg1/pyth), 12 bytes

```
+hQ-tQ"aeiou
```

#### Explanation

```
+hQ-tQ"aeiou
    tQ        : Everything except first element of evaluated input
   -  "aeiou  : Remove all occurrences of a, e, i, o and u from the string
+hQ           : Prepend first element of evaluated input
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K6gsyfj/XzsjULckUCkxNTO/9P9/pezipPzUrMK09OSixNKKgvLMspKqvJScjNxKJQA)

Answer (score 1):

## [Ruby](https://www.ruby-lang.org/) `-p`, <s>22</s> 19 bytes

```ruby
gsub /\B[aeiou]/,''
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##BcFNGkAgEADQfaewa8PXHVwDiyLJT5OaQQ5vvJfIFGaXyVSqbzttPdCgaimZvdBoRQTUCGLLBux6zm5Mmp54@wvfMO3LUT6I6CFkbuIP)

Thanks to Command Master for -3 bytes.

Comment: 19 chars: `gsub /\B[aeiou]/,''`

Answer (score 1):

## [JavaScript (V8)](https://v8.dev/), 42 bytes

```javascript
s=>s[0]+s.substr(1).replace(/[aeiou]/g,'')
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##bco9EsIgEEDh3mOkCYxKtLOJF8mk2CAgEbPILvhzebR20n7vzVCAdPKR9@VUbV@pP9NwGLekKE/ESRylSiYG0EZ0AxiPeezcrm1l1bgQBqMCOmFF4xspN38WkYFxJQCbFb3RhGZ@WKcT5Fd8@sKf5RKu9/dvrl8)

Comment: Replace substr with slice to save 1 byte

Answer (score 1):

## [Stax](https://github.com/tomtheisen/stax), 5 [bytes](https://github.com/tomtheisen/stax/blob/master/docs/packed.md#packed-stax)

```
ö¶╫♂.
```

[Run and debug it](https://staxlang.xyz/#p=9414d70b2e&i=i%0Aate%0Apotato%0Aksboejqfgcrauxpwivtzndlhmy+&m=2)

Answer (score 1):

## [Japt](https://github.com/ETHproductions/japt) v2.0a0, 7 [bytes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO/IEC_8859-1)

```
Î+UÅr\v
```

[Try it](https://petershaggynoble.github.io/Japt-Interpreter/?v=2.0a0&code=zitVxXJcdg&input=ImF0ZSI)

Answer (score 1):

## [Arturo](https://arturo-lang.io), 29 bytes

```
$[s][replace s{/\B[aeiou]}""]
```

[Try it](http://arturo-lang.io/playground?sigV3Z)

Answer (score 1):

## [Vyxal](https://github.com/Vyxal/Vyxal) `s`, 5 bytes

```
ḣkvF"
```

[Try it Online!](https://vyxal.pythonanywhere.com/#WyJQcyIsIiIsIuG4o2t2RlwiIiwiIiwiYWpzZ291ZSJd)

Port of the 05Ab1e answer but one less byte because flags are cool

Answer (score 0):

## [SNOBOL4 (CSNOBOL4)](http://www.snobol4.org/csnobol4/), 66 bytes

```
 INPUT LEN(1) . F REM . I
V I ANY('aeiou') =:S(V)
 OUTPUT =F I
END
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K87LT8rPMfn/X8HTLyA0RMHH1U/DUFNBT8FNIcjVF0h7coUpeCo4@kVqqCemZuaXqmsq2FoFa4Rpcin4h4aAtNi6ARW5@rn8/1@QX5JYkg8A)

Answer (score 0):

## [CJam](https://sourceforge.net/p/cjam), 15 bytes

```
l_0=\1>"aeiou"-
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S85KzP3/PyfewDbG0E4pMTUzv1RJ9///gvySxJJ8AA)

It's 15 bytes because there is no better way to push all those vowels.

### Explained

```
l_0=\1>"aeiou"-
l_                  e# Take the input and duplicate it: [input, input]
  0=                e# From the input, take the first character: [input, input[0]]
    \               e# Swap the top two items: [input[0], input]
     1>             e# Drop the first character: [input[0], input[1:]]
       "aeiou"      e# Push the string "aeiou": [input[0], input[1:], "aeiou"]
              -     e# Remove all occurances of the above string from the input[1:] and print.
```

Answer (score 0):

## TI-Basic, 58 bytes

```
Input Str1
sub(Str1,1,1
For(I,2,length(Str1
If not(inString("AEIOU",sub(Str1,I,1
Ans+sub(Str1,I,1
End
Ans
```

Takes input as all capital letters (which is hopefully allowed).

Answer (score 0):

## [Uiua](https://uiua.org), 16 [bytes](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/265917/97916)

```
⍜↘(▽¬∊,"aeiou")1
```

[Try it!](https://uiua.org/pad?src=RiDihpAg4o2c4oaYKOKWvcKs4oiKLCJhZWlvdSIpMQoKRiAiaSIKRiAiYXRlIgpGICJwb3RhdG8iCkYgImtzYm9lanFmZ2NyYXV4cHdpdnR6bmRsaG15Igo=)

```
⍜↘(▽¬∊,"aeiou")1
⍜↘(           )1  # apply (...) to the input except the first letter
   ▽¬∊,"aeiou"    # remove vowels
```